# Google Street View not working on the new iPad (3rd generation iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps

Trying to use the Google Street View in Safari is crashing in the new iPad. Here's a link for reference: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/streetview/mobile/gallery.html#!/id=258

The same thing works fine in iPad 2. Has anyone faced similar problems? Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to bother Safari for this. Just use the "Maps"-app for it! 
Open the app, navigate to your address and tap on the red pin.

To activate Street View, toggle the little red guy.

[image]
[image]